# What are software and hardware requirements for Scala language?

Tags: scala

I was wondering, what software and hardware requirements are there to make Scala work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

> The Scala software distribution can be installed on any Unix-like or Windows system. It requires the Java runtime version 1.5 or later, which can be downloaded for instance from Sun Microsystems or IBM.

[(source)](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

There are no special hardware requirements. You just need a hardware which is able to run Java 6 or above.

Scala 2.11.x can be installed on any platform with a Java Runtime Environment (JRE), version 6 (aka Java 1.6.0_xy) or later. Alternatively, you can use a Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 6 or later as it also includes a JRE.

Scala 2.12 – which is not released yet – requires Java 8 (aka Java 1.8.0_xy).

http://www.scala-lang.org/download/#Software_Requirements

If you want to use Scala in a Maven project it is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
```